# Если SMTP сервер отправляет почту с нестандартно порта (например 2525) то и почтовый сервер (получатель) должен слушать на этом же порту?

Tags: email, smtp

Т.е. с нестандартного порта не получится отправить письмо на gmail например?

Хостер блокирует исходящие соединения с 25, 465 и 587 портов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отправитель связывается с некоторым портом, причем обычно вообще не указывается, с каким - что свободно, то система и отдаст - и вызывает получатель, указывая его адрес и порт.

Никакой связи между портом отправителя и получателя нет. Получатель прослушивает объявленный порт (скажем, smtp - 25) или порты (ну, там, работа с SSL или еще какая), но он не обязан и не может прослушивать все порты, с которых к нему обращаются.